# How to return a clean message for nested validation error on NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have a nested form validation on my nestjs application, that returns the following result when a field has some error:

Current error message: `"products.0.amount A quantidade do produto é obrigatória"`

Expected error message: `"A quantidade do produto é obrigatória"`

For those examples above, I have a form with an attribute called `product` that is an array of objects

The issue is that I don't want to return the property name appended to the message, I want to return a clean message, readable for end users

```
export class CheckoutForm {
  @ValidateNested({ always: true })
  @Type(() => ProductForm)
  products: ProductForm[];
}
export class ProductForm {
  @IsString({ always: true, message: 'O nome do produto é obrigatório' })
  name: string;

  @Min(1, { always: true, message: 'O preço do produto é obrigatório' })
  value: number;

  @IsNotEmpty({
    always: true,
    message: 'A quantidade do produto é obrigatória',
  })
  amount: number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Luis Monsalve answer, you can make your code a bit cleaner and more versatile. I just added a helper function that returns an array of all errors.

Defualt validation error from the NestJS ValidationPipe looks like this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 422,
  "message": [
    "name must be longer than or equal to 3 characters",
    "name must contain only letters (a-zA-Z)"
  ],
  "error": "Unprocessable Entity"
}
```

So we can add the helper function getCustomValidationError to save this format. And we can use getAllConstraints helper function to get all error messages from validators without prefixes like this "products.0.amount".

```
function getAllConstraints(errors: ValidationError[]): string[] {
  const constraints: string[] = [];

  for (const error of errors) {
    if (error.constraints) {
      const constraintValues = Object.values(error.constraints);
      constraints.push(...constraintValues);
    }

    if (error.children) {
      const childConstraints = getAllConstraints(error.children);
      constraints.push(...childConstraints);
    }
  }

  return constraints;
}
```

```
function getCustomValidationError (message: string | string[]) {
  return {
    statusCode: 422,
    message,
    error: 'Unprocessable Entity',
  }
};
```

And add useGlobalPipes in main.ts file:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
  exceptionFactory: (errors: ValidationError[]) => new HttpException(getCustomValidationError(getAllConstraints(errors)), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST),
}));
```

If you are not using a global validation pipe you can do it locally in a controller method, use @UsePipe decorator. Note that this will not work if there is a global pipe, as it will be executed after the controller method pipe.

```
@Post()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe(exceptionFactory...))
yourControllerMethod() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 5.5.0 nestjs have a method to modify the errors on class-validator and class-transformer.

in your main.ts you should have

```
  await app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
```

this method receives a parameter named "exceptionFactory", which receives a function that can return an exception. if you want to modify and specific error you can do something like this

```
   await app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    exceptionFactory: (errors: ValidationError[]) =>
    {
      const customError = errors.map((el) =>
      {
        if(el.constraints.isString)
        {
          return "O nome do produto é obrigatório"
        }

        if(el.constraints.isNotEmpty)
        {
          return "A quantidade do produto é obrigatória"
        }

      });
      
      return new HttpException(customError, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }));
```

notices I have an array of errors this is because I use graphql maybe in your case in REST is different however if you console.log this errors you get an array whit this values

```
[
  ValidationError {
    target: SignUpInput {
      confirmPassword: '123',
      email: 'text@gmail.com',
      name: '',
      password: '123',
      surname: ' '
    },
    value: '',
    property: 'name',
    children: [],
    constraints: {
      minLength: 'name must be longer than or equal to 3 characters',
      isAlpha: 'name must contain only letters (a-zA-Z)'
    }
  }
]
```

in the constraints elements are the errors of the validations do you have whit this you can modify the errors.

IMPORTANT: "exceptionFactory" should return a valid exeption otherwise it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an open issue with class-validator.
https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/614#issuecomment-807255434

Seems to be nested validation issues if more than one level, which would explain the issues that you are having.