# Get min constraints from class-validator in nestjs ValidationPipe exceptionFactory

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I want to create a nestjs app and want to have the ability to customize the messages of class-validator, so I created a function to get keys I provide to messages and then returns the customized message, the problem is I want to get min value I provide to `@Min` decorator in DTOs; but it does not exist in error object I get in `exceptionFactory`.

this Is the DTO:

```
class GetUsersDto {
  @ApiProperty({ required: false })
  @IsOptional()
  @Min(1, { message: 'validation.min' })
  @IsInt()
  @Transform((param) => parseInt(param.value, 10))
  page?: number;
}
```

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      stopAtFirstError: true,
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transform: true,
      exceptionFactory: (errors) => {
        console.log(errors);
        const result = errors
          .map((error) => {
            const key = Object.values(error.constraints)[0];
            const message = getMessage(key, error);
            return message ? message : getMessage('validation.400');
          })
          .join('');
        return new BadRequestException(result);
      },
    }),
  );
```

When I log errors inside exceptionFactory I get something like this:

```
[
  ValidationError {
    target: GetUsersDto { page: -1 },
    value: -1,
    property: 'page',
    children: [],
    constraints: { min: 'validation.min' }
  }
]
```

what I need is to get the minimum value I provided to `@Min` (which is 1 here), but I get `validation.min`. How can I get the value provided to `@Min`?.

we can use context, but providing the same value in two places is error prone and adding context is making decorators a little bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global const for that value. like this:

```
const MIN_PAGE = 1

class GetUsersDto {
   @ApiProperty({ required: false })
   @IsOptional()
   @Min(MIN_PAGE , { message: 'the min value page is:' + MIN_PAGE })
   @IsInt()
   @Transform((param) => parseInt(param.value, 10))
   page?: number;
}
```

and then you will be able to use that const wherever you want. Yo can even use a separated constans.js file and store all the config values there and import them wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks, but f it was just one route and DTO and one API, yes I could do that, but it is not applicable way for an app with lots of routes, I need to validate lots of things and I need to access all the constraints automatically. also you can see that I have a message parser, so I can not use this method at all.

Comment: maybe you can use errors midlware like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71975630/how-to-return-a-clean-message-for-nested-validation-error-on-nestjs